# Ignoring an Admin with specific command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have created a anti-abuse command where I want to ignore Administrators of the server and I have used this like
`const permission = [PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator];`
`if (message.member.permissions.has(permission)) return;`
And it gives this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null ( reading "permissions)
```

It would be great if someone helps me!

I was expecting that it would ignore Administrators and take action though the members..

Comment: What is `message`? Can you add that part of your code too?

Comment: Its anti-swear command and there are multiple words if any swear if found in chat it deletes the message.. But i want to ignore Admin of the server. And I defined the code for this function and its giving an error.(Defined as well)